# I cant debug my dotnet project anymore. Could not load source error occurs

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, vscode-debugger

Whenever I try to debug I get this message.

```
Could not load source 'z:\home\shaffaaf\Code\*****\DotnetProject\Services\FileManager\S3FileManager.cs': Incorrect format of 'source' message..
```

the output of dotnet --list-sdks:

2.2.105 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]

I have tried dotnet clean & build multiple times with no differences in outcome.

New projects work fine and previous versions of this project work fine. But I can't see how any code changes could contribute to this behavior.

Comment: Can you recreate this error with a brand new project? Also, please consider taking a look at the article on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as it will give you hints and tips on how to help the community to get the answer to your issues in the quickest way possible.

Comment: No this error does not occur on new projects. There are 2 dotnet 2.1 projects which Im having trouble debugging. Current dotnet version is 2.2.3.

Comment: What is the output of `dotnet --list-sdks`?

Comment: the output of dotnet --list-sdks
2.2.105 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="2.8.2" />-->
```

^^ I had this line on my csproj. Dont remember why I added it. After removing everything is back to normal.